# Problems with finding queue for JMS communication: "Can't find a resource named..."

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jms

I am writing simple JMS application and I am trying to make message producer class communicate with MDB via queue. I've added appropriate declaration in standalone-full.xml:

```
<jms-destinations>
    <jms-queue name="statusQueue">
        <entry name="queue/statusQueue"/>
        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/statusQueue"/>
    </jms-queue>
   .
   .
   .
<jms-destinations>
```

and this is how I am trying to make connection with the queue in the message producer class

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Notifier {
    @Resource(mappedName = "java:/ConnectionFactory")
    private ConnectionFactory cf;

    @Resource(mappedName = "java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/statusQueue")
    private Queue queueExample;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

and the error i get:

**javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYWELD0049: Error injecting resource into CDI managed bean. Can't find a resource named java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/statusQueue defined on private javax.jms.Queue persistance.Notifier.queueExample**

I've already tried making connection without annotations, using `InitialContext` but the poblem stayed the same. I am using Wildfly 10.0.10. Everything seems correct for me, what may be problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating a queue via WildFly Management Interface which can be entered at http://localhost:8080/